# Uploading libraries to Azure using AzureML

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I've been experimenting a bit with the AzureML package. It weems works fine *unless* there is a need for external libraries.

Consider the following code (the function *fun* usually does quite a bit more):

```
fun<- function (b5) {
    res <- require(rmarkdown)
    res
}

test <- as.data.frame(
    cbind(
        c(0.0,  0.3,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0),
        c(0.0,  0.0,  0.0, -0.4,  0.0),
        c(0,      0,    0,    0,    0))
)


api <- publishWebService (
  ws,
  fun = fun,
  name = "Talection-fun",
  inputSchema = test,
  packages = c("talection","psych","jsonlite","rmarkdown","knitr")
)
```

The service returns FALSE

```
Created new folder: /var/folders/zf/587__ss15z7_tq240vtpb68c0000gn/T//Rtmpyu2qRC/dir138e46cbc778f/packages/bin/windows/contrib/3.1
Request failed with status 401. Waiting 9.7 seconds before retry
..........    ans
1 FALSE
Sourced file '/Users/roffe/Documents/talections/code/Web Services/WebServices.R'
```

It seems that *knitr*, *psych* and *jsonlite* work OK, whereas *rmarkdown* and *talection* (all of which are binary packages in a miniCRAN repository) apparently are located and uploaded, but not installed. Because there's an error message if I remove them from the miniCRAN repository.

Is there a way to trace what happens to the libraries? Or anything else I can do to make this work?

All suggestions and comments appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that would attempt installation of packages from any sort of repo that are not yet available... in the R _library_. There is an R function that would seem informative: `?installed.packages`

Comment: 42, I appreciate your efforts, but unless you have experience using the AzulreML package, there is no way you can understand what the code does.

Comment: You said those two packages were not yet installed.That's easy enough to understand.

Comment: You could try to update [AzureML](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/AzureML#installation-instructions) library. It might help

Answer (score 1):

According to the developers, the problem is with the miniCRAN package, which is required by AzureML. miniCRAN is responsible for uploading and installing packages to Azure. They are working on a patch.